# C# proxy question

Tags: c#, design-patterns, libraries, proxies

Does someone know library, that reduces amounts of boilerplate code when writing object proxies?

*My proxies right now look the following way and I think it's a nasty approach :)*

```
public class SampleTenantProxy : Tenant
{
    public override int? Id
    {
        get { return tenant.Id; }
        set { tenant.Id = value; }
    }
    public override String Code
    {
        get { return tenant.Code; }
        set { tenant.Code = value; }
    }

    public override String Name
    {
        get { return tenant.Name; }
        set { tenant.Name = value; }
    }

    public override Decimal Price
    {
        get { return tenant.Price; }
        set { tenant.Price = value; }
    }

    private readonly Tenant tenant;

    public TenantListBoxProxy(Tenant tenant)
    {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most **Dependency Injection tools** (such as *Windsor Castle* - have a look [here](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html)) can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Castle Dynamic Proxy -> http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html